# SilverStripe Image Fill Function is causing a server error

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am trying to do on the fly cropping inside of silver stripe. In the past we used

```
$Article_Image->SetWidth(390)
```

It worked. It returned an image of the correct width. However I now want to return an image that's using the fill function to return a 390 x 235 image. What I've got so far returns a 'server error', but it doesn't return any useful error.

Inside my newsArticle class I have the following:

**Controller - current**

```
class newsArticle extends Page {

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Article_Image' => 'Image'
    );
    public function ResizedImage() {
      return $this->Article_Image()->Fit(390,235);
    }
}
```

and then inside my page template I have the following:

**Template - current**

```
<% if $Article_Image %>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 nopadding">
        $ResizedImage()
    </div>
<% end_if %>
```

**Already tried**

I have already tried to just do $Article_Image->Fit(390,235) inside the template but it doesn't work. I have also tried the following code but it returned the error 'Cannot call method Fit() on non-member object'

**Controller - already tried**

```
class newsArticle extends Page {

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Article_Image' => 'Image'
    );
    public function ResizedImage($Image) {
      return $Image->Fit(390,235);
    }
}
```

**Template - already tried**

```
<% if $Article_Image %>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 nopadding">
        $ResizedImage($Article_Image)
    </div>
<% end_if %>
```

How can I get it to return an image that's been made to fit a particular dimension? I'm sure it can be done because it's been mentioned here in Silverstripe's documentation:
https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/files/images/

I'm using silverstripe 3.1.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to do the following in your template.

```
$Article_Image.CroppedImage(390,235)
```

You don't need to have a `ResizedImage` function in your controller.

This is a link to the version 3 docs:

https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/files/image/

The Fit method was introduced in SS4.

Comment: This is what happens when you keep switching between SS3 and SS4 I guess. Thank you so much!